# H1 image link has line under it

Tags: html, css

No matter what i try, when i preview it theres no link but when i go on my actual site there is a line underneath.

```html
<a   href="https://www.test.com/" class="image-link"><img src="as.png" alt="test" height="236" width="420"> </a>
       <p>  &zwnj;   test </p>
```

My css is here: https://pastebin.com/5c9dm0b0

I've looked up every tutorial on how to get rid of it, but its still there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
a {
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your CSS file at line no 31 extra `}` remove that and try

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```